# Naming functions in R

Tags: r

I have a set of files based on which I expect to load RDS files like R1-Tn5-NHP-55_NA and R1-Tn5-NHP-42_NA but the code is producing just the name of the 55 files not both 55 and 42.

```r
#standardize N set names  
rename_KP_set <- function(sample_name_vector)  {
 new_sample_name_vector <- apply(sample_name_vector, 
      function(x){     
         if (grepl("42",x[3])){     
           c(x[1:3],'55',x[5])
         } else if (grepl("55",x[3])) {
           c(x[1:3],'NHP',x[5])    
         } else if (grepl("55",x[3])){
           c(x[1:3],'NHP',x[5])
 } else
c(x[1:3],'55',x[5])
 }  
}) %>% 
     sapply(paste, collapse='-')   
     return(new_sample_name_vector) 
 }
```

How I can get separate rds files having 42 and 55 numbers or for that matter any rds with some number attached to them?

I have already [posted this question on Stack overflow on February 27th, 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548867/naming-function-in-r) but have got no answers so I am reposting that in Stack exchange bioinformatics in search of an answer. Any help on this issue will be considered useful.

Comment: Your question has a few wording issues. For example, what do you mean by "...a set of files based on which I expect to load RDS files..."? Provide sample input, expected output and actual output. You'll probably figure out the problem on your own as you prepare these items.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide us with input files and expected output so we can reproduce the problem and test our solutions. We cannot work on a problem if we cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Can you please explain what your function is trying to do? It's not clear to me from just looking at the function.